# Extracting Numbers out of a String and put it in an array objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have a UITextField that has data in it separated by commas (i.e, 1,2,4) I want to look at this string and extract all the numbers out of it that are separated by the commas and put it in and array. So in this example 1 2 4 would be stored in an array. Can someone help me code something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, no problem.

```
NSString *s = @"1,2,4";
NSArray *numbers = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Now you have an array of `NSString` objects - something like `{ @"1", @"2", @"4" }`.  You can convert those to `NSNumbers` or to regular integer types if you like.  Here's a link to the [`NSString` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing else in your string of commas and digits, then you can use something like `[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","]`. Then you'd just need to reiterate over returned array and type-cast each element. If there's some sort of "info-noise" you may want to look into `NSScanner` class reference.